# how to fix this cannot install anything in kali linux even on terminal here's what it says when try to command anything

Tags: kali-linux

```
root@kali:~# apt-get install dropbox.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dropbox.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dropbox.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dropbox.deb'
root@kali:~# apt-get install gdebi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gdebi is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gdebi' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg -i dropbox.deb`
And it is not recommended to use kali if you're new to Linux.